# Cannot send Json response when using Axios in Node.js server

Tags: node.js, express, axios

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const {json, urlencoded} =  require("body-parser")
const axios = require('axios')

app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false }))

//app.use(json())

app.get("/" , (req , res) => {
    axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/haitruonginfotech')
    .then(response => res.send({success : true , response}))
    .catch(error => res.send({success : false , message : error}))
})

app.listen("3001",() => console.log("Server started"))
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: Because the properties set on Errors are configured as non-enumerable.So you got `message: {}`

Comment: Axios sends the actual request body in `response.data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minor change to the code should get this working, the error wasn't in Axios, it's in Express, attempting to convert the whole (circular) response structure to Json.

Also, I wouldn't send back the whole error object, since this does not serialize nicely, better to send selected properties, for example the message.

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const axios = require('axios')

app.get("/" , (req , res) => {
    axios.get("https://api.github.com/users/janbodnar")
    .then(response => res.send({success : true , response: response.data}))
    .catch(error => res.send({success : false , message: error.message}))
})

app.listen("3001",() => console.log("Server started"))
```